# Bootstrap 3.0 carousel wordpress gallery post format

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, gallery, carousel

I'm trying to use bootstrap 3.0 carousel to show gallery posts-formats in index.php. I'm trying to build a function with this outpout for each foto from gallery post:

```
<div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1500X500">
</div>
```

This is the function code I'm working with:

```
function slider ($post) {

    // Recuperamos las imágenes de la primera galería de la entrada.
   // Ojo, esta función es nueva en WordPress 3.6
    $gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post );

    // Preparamos una variable para guardar el resultado.
    $fotos = '';

    // Para cada imagen de la galería...
    foreach( $gallery as $image ) {

        // Rellenamos nuestra variable con el contenido.
        // Adaptamos el formato para el plugin Supersized:
        $fotos .= "$image";
    }

    // Eliminamos la coma del final, especialmente problemática 
    // para navegadores obsoletos, como Internet Explorer 8

    // Imprimimos la lista de fotos con el formato deseado
    echo $fotos;

}
```

The problem is this funcition print de url of image but I don't know how add html code for each one.

any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
// Imprimimos la lista de fotos con el formato deseado
    echo '<img src="' . $fotos . '">';
```

Comment: Must be: echo '<div class="item"><img src="'. $fotos .'">' I tried but carousel doesn't work. I guess I need image caption and title too :S

Comment: Not working! for each url I retrieve with that function I need this outpout <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>

Comment: It should be very easy to adapt this to your needs - brush up on the basics of PHP (particularly string concatenation).

Comment: I'm sure solution is so easy but I'm really getting stuck :( I'm going to look for string concatenation and try to resolve it! Thanks!